# Detect Android device from BLE device (How bluetooth works ?)

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to know how bluetooth works with Android : when you turn bluetooth on, is it broadcasting data that other devices can detect ? If not, is it possible to detect from a BLE device if a specific Android with the bluetooth turned on is nearby ? And how ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this a [programming-related question](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html), like [how to use BluetoothSocket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959498/how-bluetooth-works)/[how to connect it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797692/how-does-a-bluetooth-socket-connection-work-on-android), or you just want the [theory of how bluetooth works](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/bluetooth.htm) (which has nothing to do specifically with Android) ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible with "classic" Bluetooth, but not with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). In BLE, the *peripheral* device (the beacon, keyboard, or whatever) broadcasts adverts. The *central* device (the phone) just listens for those adverts.

The central device only sends anything when it wants to connect to a particular BLE peripheral. You can detect that using a BLE *sniffer* device, but not with an ordinary BLE peripheral (other than the one the phone is connecting to), because the BLE hardware itself filters out packets that aren't intended for that peripheral.