# Why my Android 5.1 MEDION E4506 smartphone fails to detect BLE smart band?

Tags: troubleshooting

Why my Android 5.1 MEDION E4506 smartphone fails to detect BLE smart band ?

from
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le

"Android 4.3 (API level 18) introduced built-in platform support for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) in the central role and provides APIs that apps can use to discover devices, query for services, and transmit information.

and next

"Set up BLE

Before your application can communicate over BLE, you need to verify that BLE is supported on the device, and if so, ensure that it is enabled. Note that this check is only necessary if <uses-feature.../> is set to false.

If BLE is not supported, then you should gracefully disable any BLE features. If BLE is supported, but disabled, then you can request that the user enable Bluetooth without leaving your application.

I have installed Lefun Health, Yoho Sports, which should work with my BLE smart band.
Unfortunately, my smartphone, installed apps fails to discover my smart band.

I have bluetooth enabled in smartphone and smart band is not discovered.

Since my ffriend, using iPhone succeeded to connect to my smart band, so it looks BLE is enabled and on

Are you aware of any BLE service generic app to detect, where is the problem ?

My smartphone is MEDION E4506 (Lenovo, so Android 5.1 should support BLE, so let me know what fails
and do I really need to get a newer smartphone ?

similar question
[Detect Android device from BLE device (How bluetooth works ?)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/149635/detect-android-device-from-ble-device-how-bluetooth-works)

thank you

Comment: There are plenty of Medion devices running Android 5.1. We need the exact model name. Please open Settings -> Phone info and add the model name to your question (you can edit your question).

Comment: Thank you Robert, just edited.

Basing on ""Android 4.3 (API level 18) introduced built-in platform support for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) I assumed, Android 5.1 supported BLE by default.
If disabled, I would like to run CLI command to get it enabled, since Bluetooth works fine and no menu option for BLE

Comment: Android 5.1 has support for Bluetooth LE but it seems you phone on hardware level has only support for Bluetooth 4.0 without the optional BLE profile.

Comment: Do you mean extra BLE chip is reuired ?

Comment: Yes I assume the hardware is the problem. Unfortunately Aldi/Medion never published a detailed hardware spec of that device, it just says "quad core cpu" without manufacturer or type name.

Comment: Thank you
So it's the right time to say bye bye to smartphone inventions by Aldi/Medion, not supporting BLE, OTG